# What is wrong with this code i am having: causes java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

Can you see the problem in my code? I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:  
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
```

With this code:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.latest_events_fragment, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.events_recycler);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager );
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");;
    // specify an adapter
    adapter = new EventsRecyclerAdapter(list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    return view;
}
```

here is my .xml file it's called events_list.xml
`

`

Comment: You probably made a mistake with the recyclerview id. Post your layout xml

Comment: Really? In a comment? Post it in your question, dude. It'll be easier to read

Answer (score 1):

Your recycler view object is null. Make sure you are using correct id when trying to find it here:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.events_recycler);
```

If the id is correct then make sure you are using the layout you want.